# F# convention for brace placement

Tags: f#, convention

Is there a generally accepted convention for brace placement in F#? I found some examples in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/sequences), but they didn't seem to be consistent with each other. In particular, and to take an actual example, is there a consensus as to which is better, this

```
seq {
    for polarity, a in Set.filter (fun (polarity, _) -> polarity) c do
    let c = Set.remove (polarity, a) c
    for a0, a1 in orientations (eqn a) do
    for polarity, b in Set.filter (fun (polarity, _) -> polarity) c do
    let c = Set.remove (polarity, b) c
    for b0, b1 in orientations (eqn b) do
    match unify a0 b0 with
    | None ->
        ()
    | Some m ->
        yield 
            c                                            
            |> Set.add (true, equal (a0, a1))                                        
            |> Set.add (false, equal (a1, b1))                                        
            |> evalClause m }
```

or this?

```
seq {
    for polarity, a in Set.filter (fun (polarity, _) -> polarity) c do
    let c = Set.remove (polarity, a) c
    for a0, a1 in orientations (eqn a) do
    for polarity, b in Set.filter (fun (polarity, _) -> polarity) c do
    let c = Set.remove (polarity, b) c
    for b0, b1 in orientations (eqn b) do
    match unify a0 b0 with
    | None ->
        ()
    | Some m ->
        yield 
            c                                            
            |> Set.add (true, equal (a0, a1))                                        
            |> Set.add (false, equal (a1, b1))                                        
            |> evalClause m 
}
```

And similarly for square brackets in list and array literals that are too large to be written on one line - is it usual to follow the same convention?

Comment: In this case, it doesn't matter. I would be more concerned with indentation instead. *All* examples use indentation. These snippets don't. It's hard to understand how many loops there are. Did you really want to perform 4 separate loops? Does it even compile, given that the second independent loop seems to need `a`, which is only defined in the first?

Comment: In F# indentation is significant but braces don't matter all that much.  I suspect your code won't even compile due to incorrect indentation. Once you correct this, you'll see that the placement of the ending brace will go unnoticed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Nope, it compiles and runs just fine, uses just as much indentation as it needs. And yes, the four loops are needed.

Comment: Sigh, yet ANOTHER question that was closed as "opinion-based" incorrectly. This is a real problem. This question is asking whether there is a **generally accepted** convention, not "what's your favorite style?". Either there is a generally accepted convention, or there isn't -- but this question should not have been closed. Voting to reopen.

Comment: The convention is around indentations. Nested loops should be indented. In any case, F# Power tools can format a document using the generally accepted convention. Indented nested loops, ending brace on separate line. If the more common nesting convention is broken though, the brace isn't *that* important

Comment: Furthermore, once you nest the loops you realize you could replace them with a more readable pipeline of transformations. That's another common convention - prefer pipelines over nesting loops

Comment: Whether it compiles or not, the example could have been much simpler when the purpose is only to demonstrate placement of braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is inherently difficult to assess what constitutes a "generally accepted" convention... Having said that, there are the [F# formatting conventions](https://github.com/dungpa/fantomas/blob/master/docs/FormattingConventions.md), part of Fantomas, now also integrated in the [Visual F# Power Tools](https://github.com/fsprojects/VisualFSharpPowerTools). They discuss placement of braces in records and lists. According to that, the closing brace of a record, or closing `]` of a list, should be on the list line - as long as the construct enclosed is not too long. For long constructs, as is the case in your example, the brace should be on a new line.

However, [they also say](https://github.com/dungpa/fantomas/blob/master/docs/FormattingConventions.md#records):

> Not everyone likes this style, and variation is ok. For large constructs (> 6 lines) the closing token can be on a fresh line

There is no explicit mention of `seq { ... }`, but I feel that the same logic would apply there. Hence, your second example would be the preferred one.

As for the second part of your question, about arrays and lists: If you go with the Fantomas conventions, short arrays and lists would have their closing thing on the list item, large ones on a new line.